# inversion without an auxiliary VS inversion with an auxiliary

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, inversion

I know that if a sentence has a negative connotation, inversion must have an auxiliary.
But if a sentence doesn't have a negative connotation, there is example №4a with an auxiliary and there are examples №1a, №2a and №3a without auxiliaries.
I'd like to find out what the difference is between an inversion without an auxiliary and an inversion with an auxiliary.

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/so-inversion-so-has-he-vs-so-does-he.3491138/post-17724316):
**(1a)** *So/thus **began** his transformation*.
my variant:
**(1b)** *So/thus **did** his transformation **begin***.
What is the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/thus-began-a-journey.3392814/post-17204509):
**(2a)** *Now **began** a new phase in his life*.
my variant:
**(2b)** *Now **did** a new phase in his life **begin***.
What is the difference between (2a) and (2b)?

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/outstanding-among-the-menu-items-were-the-tomato-soup-and-the-swordfish.3621400/post-18447693):
**(3a)** *Close on his heels **came** the dragon*.
my variant:
**(3b)** *Close on his heels **did** the dragon **come***.
What is the difference between (3a) and (3b)?

[Freakonomics; Steven Levitt, Stephen J. Dubner; p.171-172](http://christophe.heintz.free.fr/bgt/Freakonomics__A_Rogue_Economist_Explores_the_Hidden_Side_of_Everything__Revised_and_Expanded_.pdf):
**(4a)** *... tradition to change Jewish names. Thus **did** Issur Danielovitch **become** Kirk Douglas;* ...
my variant:
**(4b)** *... tradition to change Jewish names. Thus **became** Issur Danielovitch Kirk Douglas;* ...
What is the difference between (4a) and (4b)?

Comment: All the (b) variants are unidiomatic. They sound like archaic English.

Comment: @KateBunting Why is using "did" in the first three examples unidiomatic while using "did" in the fourth example is idiomatic? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii I don't think *did* in the fourth example is particularly idiomatic either.  It's still a very old-fashioned usage, but people sometimes write that way for the effect of sounding old-fashioned or formal.

Comment: Loviii, any reason you inverted the **did + base form** and **simple past** in 4? It's confusing. They should ideally all be the same. I'm guessing @Kate Bunting didn't notice the 4th one didn't fit the (a) (b) pattern and meant to say that 4a sounds archaic, not 4b.

Comment: @gotube - I _did_ notice! In my opinion, 4b sounds _even more_ archaic than 4a.

Comment: @KateBunting And you're right. Seems that structure is terrible when the subject is followed directly by its complement. Same probably goes for direct objects.

Comment: @gotube Your last comment would be a good answer.

Comment: @Loviii Thanks, but I don't think it's enough of one. My comment is just a footnote about one of the structures you're asking about. It doesn't even address your central question, which is what the difference is between those structures in general.